# List of iOS exception codes

Tags: ios, crash

I'm trying to debug a crash my app is seeing (very rare) in SBJson and I don't know how to decipher the exception code:

```
Date/Time:       2012-12-16 12:21:31.311 -0500
OS Version:      iOS 6.0.1 (10A523)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000000000defe
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x3a0a92be CFRelease + 18
1   libcache.dylib                  0x369217d2 _entry_remove + 154
2   libcache.dylib                  0x369221d8 _cache_enforce_limits + 168
3   libcache.dylib                  0x3692115e _cache_update_limits + 170
4   libcache.dylib                  0x3692156c cache_set_and_retain + 1028
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3a0fc480 -[NSCache setObject:forKey:cost:] + 52
6   CoreFoundation                  0x3a0fc442 -[NSCache setObject:forKey:] + 38
7   MyApp                       0x000c4226 -[SBJsonStreamWriter writeString:]     (SBJsonStreamWriter.m:315)
8   MyApp                       0x000c3460 -[SBJsonStreamWriter writeObject:] (SBJsonStreamWriter.m:104)
9   MyApp                       0x000c613c -[SBJsonWriter dataWithObject:] (SBJsonWriter.m:93)
10  MyApp                       0x000c5efc -[SBJsonWriter stringWithObject:] (SBJsonWriter.m:61)
11  MyApp                       0x000c14d0 -[NSObject(NSObject_SBJsonWriting) JSONRepresentation] (NSObject+SBJson.m:38)
```

Apple provides some documentation here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html

but the 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000000000defe exception code isn't listed. Anyone know where I can get a more complete list?

Comment: The exception code isn't interesting. You got a SIGTRAP though, which I believe means that an assertion failed inside of `CFRelease()`. Did anything print to the console?

Comment: The likely assertion was testing if the input value was `NULL`.

Comment: @KevinBallard the NULL was my thinking but when I set the value to NULL to force that error I get an all zeroes exception code.

Comment: Well, the source for CoreFoundation is available at [opensource.apple.com](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-744.12/CFRuntime.c), so you can see exactly how `CFRelease()` is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the json you are passing is correct? Try validating it at some third party. I use this: http://paulisageek.com/json_validator/

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Haven't caught it in the field yet so now I wait ...